# Parsing nested json in Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

below is a sample of my file , I am not able to read the json files in logstash since it has nested json field inside the message.I need to know what is the best way to read the files in logstash.

```
{
"level": "info",
"message": {
    "req": {
        "headers": {
            "host": "localhost:8080",
            "connection": "keep-alive",
            "x-forwarded-for": "192.168.1.1, 1.1.1.1",
            "x-forwarded-proto": "http"
        },
        "url": "/products?userId=493d0aec-a9a7-42a3",
        "method": "GET",
        "originalUrl": "/products?userId=493d0aec-a9a7-42a3",
        "params": {
            "0": "/products"
        },
        "query": {
            "userId": "493d0aec-a9a7-42a3"
        },
        "body": ""
    },
    "res": {
        "headers": {
            "traceid": "ac586e4e924048",
            "x-correlation-id": "57d7920d-b623-48f8",
            "content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
            "content-length": "2",
            "date": "Fri, 08 Mar 2019 09:55:45 GMT",
            "connection": "close"
        },
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": "[]"
    },
    "gateway": "internal"
},
"correlationId": "57d7920d-b623-48f8",
"timestamp": "2019-03-08T09:55:45.833Z"
```

}

this my configuration

```
input { stdin { } }

filter {
 json{
     sources => "message" 
}
}

output {
  elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your Logstash configuration?

Comment: this my cofiguration

Comment: Please update your question